# Inlineformset saves only last form

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have model Institution, which can have photos and doctors. So I used `inlineformset_factory` to implement "create Institution" feature.
So if I add two or more photos or doctors - the form saves only last ones. Why this is happening and how to fix this problem?

**models.py**

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Institution"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Institutions"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = ResizedImageField(size=[600, 600], crop=['middle', 'center'], quality=90, upload_to='institution_photos')
    rel_institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Photo"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Photos"

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rel_institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Doctor"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Doctors"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class InstitutionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Institution
        fields = '__all__'
        error_css_class = 'error'
        required_css_class = 'required'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InstitutionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False


class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = '__all__'
        error_css_class = 'error'
        required_css_class = 'required'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhotoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True

class DoctorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'
        error_css_class = 'error'
        required_css_class = 'required'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DoctorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True

InstitutionPhotosFromSet = inlineformset_factory(Institution, Photo, PhotoForm, extra=1)
InstitutionDoctorsFromSet = inlineformset_factory(Institution, Doctor, DoctorForm, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
def institution_create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = InstitutionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'a form is valid!'
            institution = form.save(commit=False)
            photo_form = InstitutionPhotosFromSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='photos', instance=institution)
            doctor_form = InstitutionDoctorsFromSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='doctors', instance=institution)
            print photo_form
            if photo_form.is_valid():
                print 'a photo_form is valid!'
                photo_form.save()
            if doctor_form.is_valid():
                print 'a doctor_form is valid!'
                doctor_form.save()
            institution.save()
            return redirect('base:institutions_list')
    else:
        form = InstitutionForm()
        photo_form = InstitutionPhotosFromSet(prefix='photos')
        doctor_form = InstitutionDoctorsFromSet(prefix='doctors')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form
    args['photo_form'] = photo_form
    args['doctor_form'] = doctor_form
    full_name = request.user.username

    return render(request, 'base/create_institution.html', locals())
```

**template**

```
<form class="the_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="." method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    {% wysiwyg_editor "id_services" %}
                    {% wysiwyg_editor "id_license_text" %}
                    {% wysiwyg_editor "id_schedule" %}
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Photos</legend>
                        {{ photo_form.management_form|crispy }}
                        {{ photo_form.non_form_errors|crispy }}
                        {% for form in photo_form %}
                            {{ form.id }}
                            <div class="inline {{ doctor_form.prefix }}">
                                {{ form|crispy }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Doctors</legend>
                        {{ doctor_form.management_form|crispy }}
                        {{ doctor_form.non_form_errors|crispy }}
                        {% for form in doctor_form %}
                            {{ form.id }}
                            <div class="inline {{ photo_form.prefix }}">
                                {{ form|crispy }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/home/">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

May be it can help. When I print photo_form, it prints me:

```
<input id="id_photos-TOTAL_FORMS" name="photos-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1" /><input id="id_photos-INITIAL_FORMS" name="photos-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="id_photos-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="photos-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="id_photos-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="photos-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" /> <tr><th><label for="id_photos-0-photo">Photo:</label></th><td><input id="id_photos-0-photo" name="photos-0-photo" type="file" /></td></tr> <tr><th><label for="id_photos-0-DELETE">Delete:</label></th><td><input id="id_photos-0-DELETE" name="photos-0-DELETE" type="checkbox" /><input id="id_photos-0-rel_institution" name="photos-0-rel_institution" type="hidden" /><input id="id_photos-0-id" name="photos-0-id" type="hidden" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well answer for this question is quite "magical" and depends with my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421898/inline-formset-adding-wrong-form).

To let inline formset save multiple records html should change to following:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Photos</legend>
    {{ photo_form.management_form|crispy }}
    {{ photo_form.non_form_errors|crispy }}
    {% for form in photo_form %}
        {{ form.id }}
        <div class="inline {{ photo_form.prefix }}">
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Doctors</legend>
    {{ doctor_form.management_form|crispy }}
    {{ doctor_form.non_form_errors|crispy }}
    {% for form in doctor_form %}
        {{ form.id }}
        <div class="inline {{ doctor_form.prefix }}">
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: what have you changed ? the is no different between them , i faced similar problem , but still cant find a solution !?

Comment: @art_cs, that was a long time ago... I guess there was an error in prefixes. Check that in my question ```photo_form``` has ```doctor_form.prefix```.

Comment: i checked , but i cant understand this is problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62252867/inline-formset-only-save-the-last-form/62259041#62259041