# inline formset only save the last form

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

i tried many ways and searched alot(googled) but no one worked for me . whenever i save my inlineformset it only save the last form , 
my models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
   book = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
   author = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
   count = models.IntegerField()
```

this is my forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['author','count']
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['book']
InlineFormset_Author = inlineformset_factory(Author,Book,form=BookForm,extra=1)
```

this is my view

```
class CreateBookView(LoginRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
model = Author
form_class = AuthorForm
def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
    context = super(CreateBookView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['book'] = InlineFormset_Author(self.request.POST)
    context['book'] = InlineFormset_Author()
    return context
def form_valid(self,form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    context = context['book']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()
        if context.is_valid():
            context.instance = self.object
            context.save()
    return super(CreateBookView,self).form_valid(form)
```

and this is my template

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{book.management_form}}
    {{form.author | add_class:'form-control col-12 col-sm-10 mx-auto'}}
    {{form.count | add_class:'form-control col-12 col-sm-10 mx-auto' | attr:'id:count'}}
    <button class="col-4 mx-auto  shadow-lg border-right border-left">insert</button>
    <div id="BOOK" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="my-modal-title" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="my-modal-title">BOOK</h5>
  <p class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button></dic>
 </div>
 <div class='modal-footer'></form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#BOOKBTN').on('click',function () {
let allValue=[];
let numberOfInput=$('#count').val();
let allContent='';
let justforName=0;
let numOfContent=$('.modal-body input').length;
for(let j=0;j<numOfContent;j++){
justforName=j+1;

allValue.push($('input[name="BOOK'+justforName+'"').val());

}
if(numOfContent!=numberOfInput){
for(let i=0;i<numberOfInput;i++){
justforName=i+1;
{% for i in book.forms %}
  allContent+='{{i.book}}';
  {% endfor %}
}
$('.modal-body').html(allContent);
}
for(let j=0;j<allValue.length;j++){
justforName=j+1;

$('input[name="BOOK'+justforName+'"').val(allValue[j])
}})})
</script>
```

i have used widget tweaks to provide classes and ids to my input fields
does i have missed something ? or i maybe i do something wrongly ?!
and i'm ready to pay to get it working 
thanks for any advice

Comment: I have the same problem, django only save the number of forms specified in the `extra` parameter. In your case 1. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It is several years since I did any work on Django but I will have a go at annotating your code and adding my thoughts.

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    context = self.get_context_data() # This line looks fine
    context = context['book'] # You are overwriting your context here, call this 
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save() # Your have a save here and one further down, this is also setting self object which may be incorrect.
        if context.is_valid():
            context.instance = self.object
            context.save()
    return super(CreateBookView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Like I said, I haven't done any Django in several years, so I am just referring to some of my old code (which may be outdated) from https://github.com/timhughes/django-cbv-inline-formset/blob/master/music/views.py#L26 which I will annotate with comments.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data(form=form)  # Get the context data for the form in question.
    formset = context['track_formset']  # Extract the formset out of the context.
    if formset.is_valid():  # Validate the formset is valid
        response = super().form_valid(form)  # Call the parent class's form_valid.
        formset.instance = self.object  # Set the formsets type (instance of self.object) so that django knows how to save it.
        formset.save()  # Save the formset here
        return response  # Send a response to the user
    else:
        return super().form_invalid(form) # Send a response to the user with invalid form information.
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , but in my case the problem is within the template , because whenever i use custom crispy form and jquery.formset.js it will work , but i want to build my own form , and still save the last form